# VMware hypervisor license

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-server

can I use VMware vsphere hypervisor license on multiple host on different network?
Apologize that one license is used in a farm in India and I will use the same license in a farm in UK. Obviously I ask if is technically possible.
Thanks

Comment: If your organization can afford multiple offices and have a 'global' presence then you need to learn how to manage UP and procure the licenses.  I would imagine they would fit into the same bucket of money it requires to have two round trip tickets from India to the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's technically possible and will work, but definitely not ethical or legal.